# How to get file extension in nutch?

Tags: solr, nutch

I add the following changes in solr-index maping.xml and add the related field in solr scheama but the content_type doesn't appear in xml result,please help me.

feild i have added in solr-index maping.xml:

```
 <fields>
    <field dest="content" source="content"/>        
    <field dest="contentType" source="contentType"/>        
  </fields>
```

feild i have added in solr schema:

```
<field name="contentType" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to request the newly added field `contentType` in your query.
Use a query like `q=text&fl=content,contentType'.

Check http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl

Comment: i add this query but only content appears in xml response and the contentType of my document is empty,i need the content type of my document in order to filter the pdf document in velocity

Comment: Does your indexed documents have right `contentType` field filled?
You can explore your index with http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler